# Python, adding user input in dictionary

Tags: python

I have written this small code, what I want to do basically is that, I want the user to enter a command e.g: LOGO and after that the user enters a name and a value for example:
LOGO name1 boy
and **key= name1 and value= boy** is added in the dictionary.
since i am new to python, this is how i thought of writing this code, but i am not sure what mistake i am doing. and help is much appreciated. Thanks

```py
#below is my attempted code: 
data = input()

if data=='LOGO':

    name , movements = input()

    D = {name: movements}

def logo():
    print(name+ "Defined")

print(logo())
```

Comment: "but i am not sure what mistake i am doing" Well, *how do you know you are making a mistake*? What happened when you tried the code, and how is that different from what you expected to happen? There are multiple things that are wrong here; you should try to follow a tutorial from the start, and you should also learn [basic debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `input` is a string, not a tuple, so `name, movements = input()` will only work if the user inputs 2 characters and not one more.

You want to process your input more carefully. Something like:

```py
name, movements = input().split()
```

`split` with split your string into a list using spaces as separators.

Happy coding

Comment: Using `strip` with `split` is redundant. `split` will already take care of all those nasty whitespaces

Comment: I have been coding in python for years and I did not know that :D thanks

Comment: That's the most fun learning something new after a long time you're using something :) From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split): *"If sep is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and __the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace__. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`."*

Answer (score 0):

```
data = input()

D = {}

if data == 'LOGO':
    name_movements = input()

    mylist = name_movements.split(' ')

    D[mylist[0]] = mylist[1]

def logo():
    print(D[mylist[0]] + ' Defined')

logo()
```